# Turning scanned black and white diagram into specific color in Photoshop

Tags: colors, adobe-photoshop

I have a black and white diagram, and want to change the lines of the diagram into a specific hex color in Photoshop (CC). I've erased the background, which I don't need, and in the hue/saturation have managed to colorize the black. The problem is that I can't find a way to set it as a *specific* color, as there's only sliders to adjust, and doing it by eye always ends up being different from what I need. Does anyone have any insight into whether or how that's possible to do?

There may be a different and better way entirely, and the method I've used is simply the thing that has got me closest to my goal but could be a dead end. The other color changing tricks I do know (selection tool, masks, and so on) are impracticable for this diagram, which contains dotted lines and lots of other fiddly bits, but as it's all one color (black) I assumed it would be easy to change in one go. It hasn't been created digitally, so I can't adjust the original.

I'm fairly new to photoshop so might be overlooking something, but after a lot of digging I can't work this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 simple steps:

- Reduce the image color depth mode to 8-bit (Indexed mode)
- Open the palette and edit the specific palette color element to another one (Image > Mode > Color Table)

Also, there are other modes to work with specific colors (Duotone, Bitmap)
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/color-modes.html#duotone_mode

Comment: Thanks for the reply—it seems to already be on 8-bit (when I go to Image > Mode the RGB Color and 8-bit channel are both ticked; I've googled how to reduce in case I need to do something else, but only find reference to this, so assume it's already on 8-bit. If that's wrong and you could clarify the steps to reduce it to 8-bit then that would be great). But when I go to the Mode bar the Color Table is grayed out, so I can't click it. Any thoughts on what to do would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert the image to RGB.

2) Use the Color Sampler Tool to add sampler in key parts of your diagram

[image]

3) You can then use a Channel Mixer adjustment layer (or a different one, according to your preference) to make adjustments to the color, while keeping an eye on the resulting values in the `Info` window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This all works to change the color, but I still don't see a way to change it to a specific hex code color. Is there a way to do that via this method? Moving the sliders gives different colors, but it's near impossible (actually impossible?) to use them to get the same red that I'm after. I need to synch the diagram with the other stuff in a color scheme, and the best I can do still looks quite 'off.'

Comment: To get a particular hex code 1) Convert the Hex code to RGB values, `RGB = Hex - 1` converted to decimal. For example, `44 33 FF` is `68R 51G 255B` but the easiest way is to go to the color picker and type in the hex code. 2) Make note of the RGB values. 3) Use the method I described in my answer to get to those numbers.